# What are the steps in producing a block in Cardano?

Tags: ouroboros

I would love a high-level overview suitable for a beginner that covers collecting transactions, proposing a block, propagating the block, and then finally verifying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's](https://youtu.be/K7c-5S-23dg) a five-minute video by Andrew Westberg talking about just this.

In short, the steps are as follows:

1. A signed transaction is submitted to the mempool of the local cardano-node.
2. mempools are constantly being synced between the nodes' peers
3. A stake pool makes a new block by taking all the transactions in their mempool and appending it to the tip of their chain. TX's included in this block are then cleared from their mempool.
4. Other nodes see the stake pool has an extra block (and hence a longer chain), so they verify the block's legitimacy, and add it to their chain. TX's in the new propagating block are also cleared from everyone's mempool.
5. Repeat until the network is synced.

Hope this helps!