# What is the exact transaction lifecycle?

Tags: plutus, cardano-cli, transaction

Something which is still fuzzy to me. What is the exact transaction lifecycle?
What happens after we submit a transaction via the cli? Does the transaction get broadcasted to the nodes directly for the validation process to kick off?
Thanks!

Comment: I asked a similar question here. It’s great that this being discussed and the external links provided in the answers have been helpful. https://cardano.stackexchange.com/q/7537/4685

Answer (score 1):

Importantly, a transaction, when sent, cannot be cancelled. One can only request forgetting about it in order to try spending (concurrently) the same UTxO in another transaction. But, the transaction may still show up later in a block and therefore, appear in the wallet.

Discovering a transaction happens regardless of a transaction being present or not as pending. Actually, only outgoing transactions are going through the pending state. Incoming ones or, outgoing ones that have been forgotten may be discovered directly in blocks.

please check here :
https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/concepts/transaction-lifecycle

[image]

Comment: Super thanks for this. This is really helpful.